# Let $M$ be an arbitrary point located inside the triangle $ABC$. Prove that $\cot\angle MAB + \cot\angle MBC + \cot\angle MCA \geq 3\sqrt{3}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Let $M$ be an arbitrary point located inside the triangle $ABC$. Prove that $$\cot\measuredangle MAB + \cot\measuredangle MBC + \cot\measuredangle MCA \geq 3\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: can you tell me what elese doyou need.The post of Jack DAurizio is cristally clear,just read the corollary

Comment: @Booldy The post of Mr. Jack D'Aurizio is good. But it is not good for me. The solution uses the corollary 18 of Volonec, but I'm not used to it, or exactly I have not been taught about it, I am a pupil and my native language isn't English. I think my problem would have other simplier solution that I could understand easily, and it will use friendlier theorems. So I will plus 1 to Mr. Jack D'Aurizio and award you the bountry. Thanks for all your helps.

Comment: Lzu-Tao,are you familiar with Van Aubel theorem for triangles

Comment: @Booldy Sorry for late answer, I'm looking forward to seeing another solution of you. :)

Comment: Lol,since you have awarded me bounty ,i own you one more solution for high school level,i will post it soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $A_1,B_1,C_1$  be the intersection points of $AM,BM,CM$ with $BC,CA,AB$ respectively, and let $D,E,F$  be the feet of perpendiculars from $M$ to $BC,CA,AB$ respectively.Then we have 
\begin{align*}
\cot \angle MAB+\cot \angle MBC+\cot \angle MCA&=\dfrac {FA} {FM}+\dfrac {BD} {MD}+\dfrac {CE} {ME} \\
&=\sqrt{\dfrac {MA^2} {FM^2}-1}+\sqrt{\dfrac {MB^2} {MD^2}-1}+\sqrt{\dfrac {MC^2} {ME^2}-1}\\
&\ge \sqrt{\dfrac {MA^2} {MC_1^2}-1}+\sqrt{\dfrac {MB^2} {MA_1^2}-1}+\sqrt{\dfrac {MC^2} {MB_1^2}-1} 
\end{align*}
Using [Van Aubel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Aubel%27s_theorem) we have
$$\dfrac {MA} {MA_1}=\dfrac {AC_1} {C_1B}+\dfrac {AB_1} {B_1C}$$
$$\dfrac {MB} {MB_1}=\dfrac {BA_1} {A_1C}+\dfrac {BC_1} {C_1A}$$
$$\dfrac {MC} {MC_1}=\dfrac {CB_1} {B_1A}+\dfrac {CA_1} {A_1B}$$
Multiplying these and applying AmGm inequality we get
$$AM\cdot BM\cdot CM\ge 8MA_1 \cdot MB_1\cdot MC_1$$
Let $\dfrac {MA} {MC_1}=a,\dfrac {MB} {MA_1}=b,\dfrac {MC} {MB_1}=c $ so ti is sufficies to prove
$$\sqrt{a^2-1}+\sqrt{b^2-1}+\sqrt{c^2-1}\ge 3\sqrt3$$ where
$$a\ge1,b\ge1,c\ge1,abc\ge8$$
This one is an immediate consequence of Jensen inequality

Answer (score 1):

Assume that:
$$M=\alpha A+\beta B+\gamma C,\quad \alpha,\beta,\gamma\geq 0,\;\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1, $$
i.e. let $[\alpha,\beta,\gamma]$ be the barycentric coordinates of $M$. The line through $M$ and $A$ has equation $\gamma y-\beta z=0$ while the line through $A$ and $B$ has equation $z=0$. By corollary $18$ of [Volonec](http://hrcak.srce.hr/file/1473),
$$\cot\widehat{MAB} = \cot A+(\cot A+\cot B)\,\frac{\beta}{\gamma}$$
hence:
$$\cot\widehat{MBC} = \cot B+(\cot B+\cot C)\,\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}$$
$$\cot\widehat{MCA} = \cot C+(\cot C+\cot A)\,\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$
and the problem boils down to proving that:
$$ \left(1+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}+\frac{\beta}{\gamma}\right)\cot A+\left(1+\frac{\beta}{\gamma}+\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}\right)\cot B+\left(1+\frac{\gamma}{\alpha}+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)\cot C \geq 3\sqrt{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\cot A+\cot B+\cot C\ge \sqrt3 \ $ and $\ \sin A\cdot \sin B\cdot \sin C\le \dfrac {3\sqrt3} 8$

are well known inequalities

$(1+\dfrac {\alpha} {\beta} +\dfrac {\beta} {\gamma})\cot A+(1+\dfrac {\beta} {\gamma} +\dfrac {\gamma} {\alpha})\cot B+(1+\dfrac {\gamma} {\alpha} +\dfrac {\alpha} {\beta})\cot C= \\ $

$\displaystyle\sum_{cyc}\cot A+\sum_{cyc}\dfrac {\alpha} {\beta} \cdot \dfrac {\sin B} {\sin A\cdot \sin C} \ge \sqrt3 +3\dfrac 1 {\left(\sin A\cdot \sin B\cdot \sin C\right)^{\frac 1 3}}\ge \sqrt3 +2\sqrt3=3\sqrt3$